# How to specify type of a class in the app.config?

Tags: c#, unity-container, app-config

I am trying to understand how to reference a class in the app.config. In this case I want to configure and microsoft unity extension in the app.config

```
<extension type="?, ?" />
```

Is it `type="assemblyName, namespace.class"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [specify the fully qualified type name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A fully qualified type name consists of an assembly name specification, a namespace specification, and a type name.

Sample:

```
"System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

In some cases you need just the "namespace + type name, assembly name":

```
"System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what syntax Unity is using, however the standard syntax (e.g. for configuration sections) is `Namespace1.Namespace2.ClassName, AssemblyName`.